# I want display different display formats for tree node content in angular

Tags: angular

I am using #treeNodeWrapperTemplate in angular, which allows me to use displayfield for formatting. But I can specify only one column for it. for example: options = {displayField:'column1'}
I want to display two values "column1(column2)" in it. Anybody has any idea about it?

Comment: Can you show the code for it? Maybe adding a package link would be useful as well.

Comment: options = {displayField: 'value'};
fields = createTree(fields);

HTML ->
<tree-root [fields]="fields" [options]="options">
  <ng-template #treeNodeWrapperTemplete let-field>
      <tree-node-content [field]="field"></tree-node-content>

Answer (score 2):

`displayField` can be a function that returns a string using the column values.So, you may use something like this to use multiple columns

```
displayField: (node) => `${node.data.column1}(${node.data.column2})`
```

Below is a detailed example of its usage.

```js
  nodes = [
    {
      _id: '1',
      column1: 'root1',
      column2: 'root1_info',
      nodes: [{_id: '3', column1: 'child1', column2: 'child1_info'}]
    },
    {
      _id: '2',
      column1: 'root2'
      column2: 'root2_info',
    }
  ];

  options: ITreeOptions = {
    idField: '_id',
    displayField: (node) => `${node.data.column1}(${node.data.column2})`,
    childrenField: 'nodes'
  };
```

Comment: does that mean I need to traverse through nodes[] to get " (node) => `${node.data.column1}(${node.data.column2})` "

Comment: No you dont have to traverse through it... just replace `displayField: 'column1'`  with `displayField: (node) => `${node.data.column1}(${node.data.column2})`. The component will do the traversal for each element (node) in the tree data source and calculate the text to be displayed

Comment: not working for me-> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-kgl5cj?file=app%2Ftreeview.component.ts

Comment: It is giving me following error -> type '(node:any) => string' is not assignable to type 'string'